# get the time from network and add time per hour in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm doing an app to allow user select duration(per hour) for the service. System will display start time and end time(depending on the duration selected) in the text view.

**User are required to enter how many hour(duration) of services requested, and the app will display the start time and end time of service on the text view.

how to get current time from network as **start time** and display the start time on text view after the service is purchased.

how to get **end time** =[startTime + duration(**per hour**: eg 1, 2, 3,..(user select with number picker))]

Comment: Can you make your question more clear. So that we guys can understand and help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int startTimeInSeconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

final int secondsPerHour = 3600;
int endTimeInSeconds = startTimeInSeconds + secondsPerHour * duration;
```

[Calendar Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)